# Why my Android ActionBar doesn't update when it is explictily changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-actionbar-compat

I've seen questions on SO that related to these many times. So I've decided to post the reason why it happens and also the solution so that many SO users will get the benefit of the answer.

For sometime now I've seen a reoccurring issue where I would change the `ActionBar` title and it would get ellipsized shorter than it should. Another symptom of this is having your title wrap when it shouldn't or just stay completely blank. When you change the the action bar buttons it wouldn't update correctly and I would be left with either no action bar buttons even though they have definitely been added or double up on existing action bar buttons.

It turns' out this is a relatively straight forward issue. It mainly happens when you use a `ViewPager` with the `getChildFragmentManager()` to manage your fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fragment that hosts the `ViewPager` and the child `Fragment`s that are created by your adapter must also call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in their `onCreate()` method's, so that all of the option menu events get passed down to the child fragments and on to their children and so on.

Simple really, when you think about it. But its just one of those things.

Hope this helps and I welcome your comments,
*Simon*

Comment: Still having the issue if the `fragment` that sets the title doesn't contribute to the `options menu`.  My only guess is that if it does contribute then the widths are recalculated.  Documented the issue on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25330553/1747491).

Comment: Your solution work likes a charm. Was struggling from so many days. None of the solutions work except this one. Thank you so much for the great solution!