# SearchView causes action bar items, title, and launcher to disappear when I try to expand

Tags: android, android-support-library, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I implemented a `support v7 SearchView` inside the `ActionBar` of a `ListFragment`.  When that ListFragment is part of a `master-detail` screen on our Nexus 7, <s>expanding it causes most of the action bar to disappear</s> expanding it after replacing the detail fragment causes most of the action bar to disappear (I wanted to clarify here because I can successfully expand it when the screen is first loaded and before I select a new detail item in the master-detail list). This disappearance does **not** happen when the ListFragment is by itself in portrait.  This problem has manifested itself **only** on our `Nexus 7` running `4.3`.  To add to this strangeness, clicking another item in the master list causes yet more of the action bar to disappear.

The SearchView is inflated / configured from the master ListFragment.  The Share icon is inflated / configured from the detail Fragment.

**Edit**: If I don't do anything to the SearchView programatically in onCreateOptionsMenu then it works fine.  Of course, it has no functionality then.

**Edit 2**: My guess is that maybe something weird is happening when I change out detail fragments in master-detail and the SearchView is expanded.  Perhaps some weird interaction with the different detail fragments' onCreateOptionsMenu invalidating while the SearchView is open.

**Edit 3**: I have also tried a custom collapsible action view rather than the SearchView and the issue is present.  This means it has to do with the expanding / collapsing I think.

[image: comparison]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem sounds like its against caused by the same indirect problem as this SO post.

[Why my Android ActionBar doesn't update when it is explictily changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089136/why-my-android-actionbar-doesnt-update-when-it-is-explictily-changed)