# Activity's title area doesn't expand if the title is set from a Fragment that doesn't contribute to the options menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, ellipsis, android-titlebar

This is very similar to the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24089136/1747491), which mostly fixed my problem.

However, if you are setting the `title` from a `fragment` that does not contribute to the `options menu`, then the title area won't expand.  This can cause an ellipsis if the initial title was very small, even though there may be plenty of room in the action bar for it.

My guess is that if the fragment does contribute to the options menu then it causes that title area's width to be recalculated.  Is there a way to force this to happen?