# ActionBar title is truncated to 1 character

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I am using an activity which hosts a `ListFragment`. From the ListFragment I can open a `DetailTabsFragment`. The two tabs host two fragments: `DetailFragment` and `ReviewFragment`.

I set the title in DetailFragment, with this code:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("my title");
```

But as you can see here in the screenshot, the title is truncated at the first character. Why is that?

[image: ActionBar screenshot]

The xml layout of DetailTabsFragment:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

An the mainActivity's layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.dcs.shows.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15389663/2745495

Comment: Yes I found that before asking my question and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. My architecture is a bit different, but the end result of the title being truncated to a single letter (T...) was the same. I too played around with every suggestion on that other SO question. Ultimately, it seemed like some sort of strange race condition with the setting of the title in the activity. I found that simply overriding the activity's setTitle function and wrapping the call to super in a postDelay runnable fixed it for me:

```
@Override
public void setTitle(final CharSequence title) {
    toolBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.super.setTitle(title);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

I'm using toolbar's postDelayed as a convenience method. But you can certainly use a handler here. Hope this helps.