# Android collapsing toolbar: How to resize the text, so that it shows full text than partially

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using CollapsingToolbarLayout:

I am using the following code to show the title:

```
collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Udupi Sri krishna Temple");
```

The text is shown as below. It shows only partial and shows .. at the end. Is there a way to control the size so that it shows full text.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First define your text styles in styles.xml

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Collapsed" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Expanded" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Note that the values are just examples; you need to change them to fit your app.  Also, you may want a different TextAppearance style as a parent.

Then in XML :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    .
    .
    .
    app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Collapsed"
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Expanded"


/>
```

in code:

```
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_MyApp_Title_Collapsed);
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_MyApp_Title_Expanded);
```

---

EDIT: In the comments there is a discussion about multi-line text.  `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does *not* support multi-line text.  Please ignore my suggestion to use `setCustomView()` on the toolbar.  According to docs:

> **Do not manually add views to the Toolbar at run time.** We will add a 'dummy view' to the Toolbar which allows us to work out the available space for the title. This can interfere with any views which you add.

Comment: The text color changes after doing that. how to change the text color to white. Also `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` looks too small. can i mention the size of the font manually

Comment: can i have multiple line text in expanded mode, So that i can use bigger font. Also add padding on right (because i may have to add a button on the right), so that it will not overlap

Comment: When i put the code in xml it didnt work. but when i put in the code it worked. Should i be putting in both.

Comment: For multiple line text, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259311/action-bar-title-with-more-than-one-line  You would need to call `setSupportActionBar()` on the Toolbar and then call `setCustomView` on the action bar, using a TextView that you have configured for multiple lines.

Comment: The XML by itself should have worked, you shouldn't need to use both XML and code.  I find it hard to get the styles to work sometimes; also, it's possible there's a bug in the support library around this.  But as long as the code works, you can go with that.