# Multiline Text view in CollapsingToolbarLayout instead of Title

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to display some text in Collapsing toolbar instead of title. Problem is that text may contain more than 1 line. So I need to use custom view, but can't understand how to implement it in proper way.

Also, how to set minimal `CollapsingToolbar` height, to always show all text lines, not collapse them to one?

Totally, I need something like this:

[image]

**Where 1 - start position and 3 - ends position (no more collapse after reaching this toolbar height).**

Comment: see this liknk may be helpfull to you...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185843/android-collapsing-toolbar-how-to-resize-the-text-so-that-it-shows-full-text-t

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you want to do customization in [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) then you need to know about that. It's easy to add `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in Android projects. If you are using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) then it's easy to add. 
Just right-click on your package like `com.project`, select **New->Activity->ScrollingActivity** and `Add` it in your project. Now you just need to do some customization with your code.

Go to your `styles.xml` file and add these 2 styles:

```
    <style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Collapsed" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Expanded" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
```

Go to your **activity_scrolling.xml** file and set those 2 styles in your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Other is add `TextView` as your requirement in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mailcollection.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Collapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Title.Expanded"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="left|bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/title_description"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When you do some customization with your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` then you need to implement some custom code in your activity file also.

Go to your **ScrollingActivity.java** file :-

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_MyApp_Title_Collapsed);
        collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_MyApp_Title_Expanded);

        // This is the most important when you are putting custom TextView in CollapsingToolbar
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");

        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    //when collapsingToolbar at that time display actionbar title
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    //carefull there must a space between double quote otherwise it dose't work
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the complete code that if you want to add Multiline `TextView` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instead of Title. I hope you will get you solution.

When you implement code like this then no need to set minimal CollapsingToolbar height, It show all text lines always according to text length.

Comment: @Shailesh Is it necessary to define Title Text Appearance in both XML and Java code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this very nice lib [here](https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar).

The README file explains everything about how to add and use the lib in your project.

Answer (score -5):

For multiline Text use below cade for Toolbar;

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/color"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"                   
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```