# How to auto resize the setTitle() text in the v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have this `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`and the `setTitle()` text I want to show sometimes does not show completely. I look for some sort of auto-resize like the  [android-autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) to use for the toolbar but of course that one dont work in `toolbar` Then I read about the [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185843/android-collapsing-toolbar-how-to-resize-the-text-so-that-it-shows-full-text-t) but I dont want that advanced toolbar. Actually I tried it but text was not resized to show all letters. maybe i did something wrong but anyway:)

Can anybody advice me what to do?

Answer (score 2):

you can add this line to your toolbar

```
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/styleX"
```

your toolbar gonna be like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:gravity="center"
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/styleX"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

here is the style

```
<style name="styleX" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
       <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

you can change 20sp dynamically if you want using dimens.xml

Comment: But how can I know programmatically during runtime that the `20sp` value is correct so that all text is resized and fully showend?

Comment: test and change in dimens.xml for different size, because programmatically getting the device density and change it sometimes doesn't work for some devices

Comment: yes what you say I can do but I was looking for some widget or hack like the wonderful [autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview).

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val toolbarText = binding.toolbar.getChildAt(1) as TextView
toolbarText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false)
toolbarText.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(toolbarText, 1, 20, 1, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP)
```

The child index may differ if you have (not) up action.

Answer (score 1):

Set AutoSize for all Toolbar TextViews (title & subtitle)

```
 public static void setToolbarTextAutoSize(Toolbar toolbar) {
        for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    ((TextView) view).setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                    ((TextView) view).setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(TextView.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```